# python - sum list of columns, even if not all there

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
   A  B  C  D  G
0  9  5  7  6  1
1  1  4  7  3  1
2  8  4  1  3  1
```

generated by this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
x=np.array([[1,2]])
df['G'] = np.repeat(x,5)
```

Suppose there are times when a certain column 'E' exists, and sometimes it doesn't depending on the time frame of the data.

So sometimes we have

```
   A  B  C  D  E  G
0  9  5  7  6  2  1
1  1  4  7  3  3  1
2  8  4  1  3  4  1
```

So either way, I'd like to sum the rows from columns A, C, and E, and groupby column G. So when column E exists , I just use

```
df.groupby('G')['A', 'C', 'E'].sum()
```

but when E doesn't exist, like in the first dataframe, it doesn't work.

What do I need to do in order to sum even if a column is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the columns you wish to sum in a list `sum_cols = list('ACE')`, and then intersect whatever DataFrame you're working with with this list.

```
df.groupby('G')[df.columns.intersection(sum_cols)].sum()
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 5)),             
                      columns=list('ABCDG'))

>>> df
   A  B  C  D  G
0  9  5  9  2  6
1  3  1  1  1  3

>>> sum_cols = list('ACE')

>>> df.groupby('G')[df.columns.intersection(sum_cols)].sum()
   A  C
G      
3  3  1
6  9  9

>>> df['E'] = [100, 200]

>>> df.groupby('G')[df.columns.intersection(sum_cols)].sum()
   A  C    E
G           
3  3  1  200
6  9  9  100
```